# How to change the size of google map with a button

Tags: jquery, google-maps

After a couple of hours searching in the web, I came about this website:
http://leonardogandini.com/projects/Google-Maps-API/map-resize
It is exactly what I wanted. Resizing the google map through a button press.

I don't have much experience with Jquery or Javascript but I'm trying to make this work. So I copied the code and try to display it.

When I input this code, the map disappeared. Am I missing something? Can anyone make this work please? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#resizeuno').click(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').css({'width':'300','height':'400'});
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  
});
$('#reset').click(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').css({'width':'855','height':'550'});
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
}); 
});
```

Have a look at the code http://jsfiddle.net/yungchristie/9P9RG/1/

Comment: Please provide a "working" and configured fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the **px** behind your widths/heights.

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9P9RG/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $mapCanvas = $('#map-canvas');

    $('#resizeuno').click(function() {
        $mapCanvas.css({'width':'300px','height':'400px'});
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $mapCanvas.css({'width':'855px','height':'550px'});
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
    }); 
});
```

Also it would be better if you just add a class, not setting the CSS via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $mapCanvas = $('#map-canvas');

    $('#resizeuno').click(function() {
        $mapCanvas.addClass('map_resize');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');  
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $mapCanvas.removeClass('map_resize');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');   
    }); 
});
```

and in your CSS this:

```
#map-canvas {
    width: 855px;
    height: 550px;
}

#map-canvas.map_resize {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```